# Attempt to dereference null object error

Tags: error, exception, null-pointer, null, unexpectedexception

I have below controller where I get Attempt to dereference a null object error at **ProdIds.add(c.id);**  Line.

**Error Code**

```
public TestController(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) 
    {   redirectUrl ='';
    templateToVfpageMap = new Map<id,String>();
        templateToVfpageMap.put('a4ZM0000000IQlCMAW','SampleFormPage_Final');
        templateToVfpageMap.put('a4ZM0000000IQl7MAG','SampleFormPage4_Final');
    TempaltesMap = new Map<id,Form_templates_abv__c>(); 
        for(Form_templates_abv__c template :[select id, Name from Form_templates_abv__c where Active_abv__c = true])
        {
            TempaltesMap.put(template.id,template);
        } 
        productMap = new Map<id,product_vod__c>(); 
        for(product_vod__c product :[SELECT  Id, Name,Dosage_Strength_abv__c,Established_Name_abv__c, Proprietary_Name_abv__c,NDC_Number_abt__c,Parent_Product_vod__r.name from Product_vod__c where Product_type_vod__c ='BRC' and Active_abv__c = 'Yes' and 
                                     Id in :ProdIds])
        {
            productMap.put(product.id,product);          
        }
       selectedUserAvailability = '0';  

       for(My_Setup_Products_vod__c  ac: [Select Id,Product_vod__r.Name,Ownerid,Name From My_Setup_Products_vod__c where Ownerid=:Userinfo.getUserId()])
         {

           for(Product_vod__c c: [Select Id,Name From Product_vod__c where Parent_Product_vod__c=:ac.Product_vod__c ])      
            {  
                 ProdIds.add(c.ID);

            }


         }
       this.Test =   (Form_Requests_abv__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();
```

Comment: I can't see you have initialized `ProdIds` in your constructor

Comment: Go to the User record that you are testing under and check the "Development Mode" checkbox. Repeat the error and the stacktrace should appear giving you the exact line number that the problem occurs at and so hopefully telling you which variable is null. Then check that that variable has been initialised (something assigned to it) before it is used at that line.

Comment: The problem is on this line.  ProdIds.add(c.ID);

Comment: @SFDC_Learner I think you need to initialize your variable in controller like `set<Id> ProdIds = new set<Id>();`

Comment: As an aside; you have nested select statements which is prone to failure due to the limits imposed by Salesforce. Investigate bulkification patterns and see if you can refactor your code.

Comment: @Ratan he is using the variable ProdIds already in SOQL here: [SELECT  Id, Name,Dosage_Strength_abv__c,Established_Name_abv__c, Proprietary_Name_abv__c,NDC_Number_abt__c,Parent_Product_vod__r.name from Product_vod__c where Product_type_vod__c ='BRC' and Active_abv__c = 'Yes' and  Id in :ProdIds]

Comment: @karthikselva If `ProdIds` is null then in SOQL I think it will not give any error. But when you try to add any value then it will give null pointer exception

Comment: @Ratan Cool I didn't knew SOQL binding variables works that way. Thank you  for the clarification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the ProdIds before it use.It will work fine.

Comment: This post would be better with a code snippet.

Comment: ProdIds = new Set<Id>();